# How do I use def __init__(self): in a class to call my sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, class, sqlite, init

I'm using Flask and I have a file of python functions: db.py, however, every time I call a function in other python files I have to call `get_db()` to get the database and I have to import the files for the function.

db.py:

```
import sqlite3
import click

from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return g.db

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

So in another file, I have to import the file (`from myapp.db import get_db`) and call `db = get_db()` to get the database.

routes.py:

```
from myapp.db import get_db

@app.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']

        db = get_db()
        error = None

       <more code here>

        if db.execute(
        'SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username,)
    ).fetchone() is not None:
        error = 'Username {} is already registered.'.format(username)

       <more code here>

        db.execute(
            'INSERT INTO user (username, password, email, signup_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
            (username, generate_password_hash(password), email, now_time)
        )
        db.commit()

       <more code here>
```

But I wanted to know if it is possible that just by calling `db.execute()` for example, it would `get_db()` naturally if I have imported it.

I'm trying to build the class like this in db2.py:

```
class DatabaseFunctions:
    import sqlite3
    import click
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db 
        db = qlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )

    def get_db(self):
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return g.db

    def close_db(self, e=None):
        db = g.pop('db', None)
        if db is not None:
            db.close()

    def init_db(self):
        db = get_db()
        with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
            db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))

    @click.command('init-db')
    @with_appcontext
    def init_db_command():
        """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
        init_db()
        click.echo('Initialized the database.')

    def init_app(self, app):
        app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
        app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

I also want to expand db2.py into a allfunctions.py file and I'm told classes are best practice. However, I struggle with the self and **init** and even with quite a bit of reading, I don't see the point in a class when you can just have a page of functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is that `g` supposed to be in your `get_db` and `close_db` methods? Also, I doubt you really want to call global functions like `get_db()` and `init_db()` rather than calling methods like `self.get_db()` and `self.init_db()`. I suspect what you really need is to work through a basic tutorial on OO first, and _then_ come back and try to apply it to your design.

Comment: To try to answer your question in simple terms: the point of having a class is that you can construct instances of that class, and you can store state that's shared between methods of that instance, by assigning values as attributes of that instance. You're not doing anything remotely like that in your code, so there is no point to your class. But it's easy to come up with examples where there _is_ a point, and any good tutorial will include such examples, which will get the idea across.

Comment: You're correct in your analysis that I haven't done much OO. Ought I to be calling self.get_db() even when using db.py? ```g``` is a global dict in flask I think. Well if you see them as unnecessary then I make no issue in removing them and will continue to just call ```get_db```. Thank you.